# How to subscribe to specific changes in a list in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a list containing all the data, when updated I want to notify specific subscribers:

example:

```
arr = [{id:1, name: 'test1'}, {id:2, name: 'test2'}];
```

**component 1:** will get notified only if the first object in the array is changed

**component 2:** will get notified only if the second object in the array is changed

Currently I am using `Subject` to emit all changes to all subscribers and then on the components I am filtering the result depending on what I need

Comment: `distinctUntilChanged` with a custom compare function.

Comment: Do you change the objects on your own? Do you know when they are going to be changed?

Comment: @canbax I am updating the list each 1 minute by calling back-end services

Comment: @martin@martin I will check your suggestion and then replay to you with the result

Comment: If your condition is only the first and second objects in the array you can make 2 separate observables and feed them.

Comment: @Eldar no the real scenario is bigger than that

Comment: @Kardon63 You can make a `BehaviorSubject` that is objects of array. You can subscribe to it and manually check if the first variable is changed or second is changed based on what you care.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `ChangeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` on your components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the subject will still be necessary, as you are saving state, but the filtering you can move to the shared service.

Create a method in the service that accepts an id parameter. Each component can now call this method with its ID, listening for only it's changes:

```js
// in your service

arrSubject = new Subject<{id, name}[]>();
...
dataHasChanged(id: string): Observable<{}> {
        return this.arrSubject.asObservable().pipe(
            map(arr => arr.filter(x => x.id === id)),
            distinctUntilKeyChanged('name') 
            // or, check if anything changed... basic string or custom compare function
            // distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === (JSON.stringify(b))
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put a public `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` in a shared service.

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
export class SharedService {
  firstPage = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  secondPage = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
}


# import the service inside the constructor of the components as usual

constructor(private _s: SharedService) { }
```

--edit--
You can make a `BehaviorSubject` that is objects of array. You can subscribe to it and manually check if the first variable is changed or second is changed based on what you care.

Comment: thanks for the reply but this is not what i am looking for, as mentioned in the question i am already using `Subject` but i don't want to push all the changes and then check in the component, i just want to get the specific changes that are important to that specific component